# Transposing data in dataframe with multiple rows per ID

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns: id and value. Each id appears in as many rows as unique values.

There are two values that i'm interested in logging, 2 & 39. Instead of having one row per value I'd like to create a new dataframe with three columns: id, value2, value39. value2 and value39 need boolean values to indicate whether or not they were registered in the original dataframe.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
I'd like to have a dataframe with one row per id. That means I need to consolidate the value2 and value39 boolean value into one row.

Comment: something like `df['value2'] = df['value'] == 2` and `df['value39'] = df['value'] == 39`?

Comment: Would you have to wrap this in a groupby function first to log the information for each id?

Comment: `groupby` is unnecessary for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a second DataFrame based on the `id` column on the first DataFrame, and then create two columns testing whether or not the value is 2 or 39.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 6, 6: 6},
                   'value': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 39, 3: 39, 4: 1, 5: 39, 6: 2}})

df2 = df[['id']]
df2['value2'] = df.value == 2
df2['value39'] = df.value == 39

EDIT:
>>> df2.groupby(['id']).any()
   value2 value39
id               
0    True   False
1    True   False
2   False    True
3   False    True
4   False   False
6    True    True
```

Comment: The above works. I added an edit to my original question. I want the new dataframe to have one row per id, which means I need to consolidate the boolean values into one row and get rid of the duplicates.